# With NetBeans 7.0, what's the latest list of APIs that can be used outside the Netbeans Platform?

Tags: java, api, swing, netbeans

The below list is based on this blog entry by Geertjan Wielenga (http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/netbeans_platform_top_10_libraries)

1. Lookup API
2. Nodes API
3. Explorer & Property Sheet API
4. Visual Library API
5. Utilities API

With the release of NetBeans 7.0, are there more such APIs that can be used outside the NetBeans platform?

Comment: maybe will be better to send this questions to correct Forum : http://forums.netbeans.org/

Comment: @jzd I think a lot of these APIs are used in regular Swing applications. That's why I put a Swing tag on it.

Comment: @mKorbel The NB forum is extremely slow and it takes a long time for comments to be shown/updated. In any case, I was about to post there as well but you commented before that: [link](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=39391)

Comment: I don't think the Swing tag is a good fit because this has nothing to do with Swing.  You use the Collections APIs in Swing but that doesn't mean you would take an ArrayList question with Swing.

Answer (score 1):

You can check http://bits.netbeans.org/7.0/javadoc/ and see if anything there fits the bill.